# How to perform Virtual Batch Normalization (VBN) in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

VBN is talked in [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03498.pdf) paper. And implemented [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/gan/python/features/python/virtual_batchnorm_impl.py), [Here](https://github.com/openai/improved-gan/blob/master/imagenet/model.py) and [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/gan/features/VBN). I donot want to go to core/full code. I just want to know, how to use VBN as keras layer, as i am not very expert tensorflow/keras coder. I generally use simple batch normalization (BN) as follows

```
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
```

In a similar way how to use VBN instead of BN in following keras code?

```
model.add(Dense(256,input_dim=self.input_dim))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))%I want to replace this with VBN
model.add(Dense(512))
......
.......
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first link they say

> The `__init__` API is intended to mimic
>     `tf.compat.v1.layers.batch_normalization` as
>     closely as possible.

So if you take a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization,
It says you use this function as ...

```
x_norm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=training)
```

So if I understand well,
using the functional API https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/,

You should probably do something like:

```
layer_n = VBN(**kwargs, layer_n-1)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I didn't understand answer completely. I gone through the link of functional you mention, completely but not find VBN function anywhere. I modified question by writing some more code, plesase help how to inserted VBN in place of BN

Comment: As I add you insert `VBN` I think it would be better to use Keras Functional API instead of Keras Sequential API? the reason is `VBN.__init__()` method requires `reference_batch` argument.
When you use the Sequential API you would do something like `model.add(VBN(**kwargs))` but this will raise an Error, 
So your better do something like:
`inputs = Input(your_inputs), dense = Dense(256)(inputs) .... vbn = VBN(leaky_relu, **kwargs)`

Comment: I think VBN is not giving output as a tensor

Comment: `from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation;
from keras.models import Model ;
inputs = Input(shape=(784,));
x = Dense(64)(inputs);
x = Activation('relu')(x);
x = VBN(x);
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x);
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x);
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions);
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
loss='categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy']);
model.summary()`

Comment: After running above code getting `
ValueError: Layer dense_31 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class '__main__.VBN'>. Full input: [<__main__.VBN object at 0x7f2d083dcf60>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
`